# User autocomplete textbox in velocity template

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

In JIRA, how can i create user picker autocomplete field into velocity template.

is there any service which can be use or any documentation or stuff helps a lot.

Thank You

Comment: Use the JIRA source to see examples of user picker fields.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, now, i don't have my.atlassian license acc to download jira stuff. it's with other administrator. i'll get stuff soon. I found  - https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Custom+Field+Plugin+Module link for custom field searcher. But i am not understand how i could use it in my velocity template which is used under "Webwork" Module. Basically, i just need user picker field to appear over screen through velocity template, and here, based on selected user, i have to list related data.